# Selenium doesn't get necessary cookie

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to get cookies of this website: [sahibinden.com](http://sahibinden.com/)
I need to print s3IssGuY1 cookie. But when I type `driver.get_cookies()` it doesn't work.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/archie/Sahibinden/geckodriver")
driver.get("https://www.sahibinden.com/")
print(driver.get_cookies())
```

Comment: Please add more information. Specifically, see the 'Reproducible' section in [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That's all in my code. I also have from selenium import webdriver but didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: You said "it doesn't work", does it give you an error? print nothing? crash? print []? - It will help people to help you by following the previously linked help guide.

Comment: It prints cookies but not the one I wanted.